# View::make in Phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I've a function that returns a `View::make($string)`. I want to test that this function did indeed return an instance of View object. `$string` points to a file that does exist.

When I try to run this function within Phpunit it doesn't seem to finish. How can I test in Phpunit that a View object was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stemmed down from usage of `var_dump` as I wanted to see the object in question. As nothing was presented in output, I assumed that had to do with `View::make` rather than outputting the object to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has helper methods specifically designed for testing views.

Some of them include:

```
$response = $this->get('/path/to-your-route');


$response->assertViewIs($value);

$response->assertViewHas($key, $value = null);

$response->assertViewHasAll(array $data);

$response->assertViewMissing($key);
```

More info can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests#available-assertions

If you need to assert that something is an instance of something else, you can try the following:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf($expected, $actual);
```

Comment: I've replicated your issue. The reason your test is "hanging" is because the view object returned is quite large. There is a lot to render to the console. I'm not sure why you are testing the `View::make()` method. Laravel already has tests written to make sure that works. Instead you should test your own logic using the solutions I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm testing that my method returns instance of `View`, indeed by using `assertInstanceOf`. I'm not testing `View::make`

Answer (score 0):

When you provide invalid string the view object will not be created and will throw an exception. Not sure what you have in your function that prevents the exception, but the way to go around this issue, is to include this line in the failing test:

```
    $this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);
```

Comment: If an exception were thrown Phpunit would show it and the process would end. If exception were caught somewhere (I'm not catching anything anywhere) the process would end. What I've got is a process that doesn't end until I terminate it. String is valid and view representing it does exist.

Comment: My bad, I've read that 'file doesn't exist'. I've did a quick test with this code and it dumped me whole view object `$test = view('auth.login');
        dd($test);` Recently I've answered in a similar thread about long processing view, and the issue turned out to be the number of MySQL requests which took a lot of time to process. Also Denis Priebe answer is a good way to go.

Comment: I've created a view `test.blade.php` which contains just string `test`. In the phpunit test I did `var_dump(view('test')); exit;` to get the same result - process just hangs without displaying anything

Comment: Can you try `dd()` instead of `var_dump()` ?

Comment: That did the trick and it does coincide with @Denis Priebe observations. Thank you!